# Switching electric boiler off for months -- any precautions?

Tags: water-heater

I have an electril 50-litre water heater (boiler) in an appartement that's going to be abandoned probably for several months. I thought about switching off the boiler's electric fuse to switch off the boiler and save money, since nobody is going to need the hot water.

[image: click to enlarge]

**Can I simply switch it off, and back on in several months, or should I do something more? Or I shouldn't do it at all?**

A photo of the (I think) crucial parts of the boiler is attached:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just switching it off should be fine.** Depending on climate, you might also want to turn off and drain the whole water system (in which case you would want to be sure to refill the water system and get any air pockets out before switching the boiler back on).

Comment: The appartment won't freeze, if that's the concern. I as well thought about some bacteria or stuff -- but that only concerns warm-but-not-warm-enough water, right?

Comment: Good idea to turn off while you're away that long in case a pipe bursts or valve leaks or breaks.